# Correct way of presenting a new screen with a stack?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a signup page with 4 steps (4 separate screens). On the first page, the user enters their username in a field, on the second page a display name, on the third their birthday, and on the fourth their password.

Here's my current signup screen file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

const SignupScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>First step</Text>
      <Button
        title="Next step"
        />
    </View>
  );
}

export default SignupScreen;
```

But I'm a bit confused as to how to present the next screen when the user taps the Button. How do I create a Stack here? Or would I do it in the App.js file?

Here is my `App.js`:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import {
  RootStack,
  TabsStack,
  SignupStack
} from './navigation/navigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator>
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="Tabs"
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          component={TabsStack}
          />
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="SignupStack"
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          component={SignupStack}
          />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And here is my `navigation.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import SignupScreen from '../screens/SignupScreen';

export const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const SignupNav = createNativeStackNavigator();

export const TabsStack = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="History" component={SecondScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Third" component={ThirdScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Fourth" component={FourthScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );

export const SignupStack = () => (
    <SignupNav.Navigator>
      <SignupNav.Screen
        name="Signup"
        component={SignupScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Sign up' }}
      />
    </SignupNav.Navigator>
  );


  function HomeScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  function SecondScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Second</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  function ThirdScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Third</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  function FourthScreen({ navigation }) {
    function onPressButton() {
      navigation.navigate('SignupStack');
    }
  
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Signup'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPressButton} underlayColor="white"><Text>{item.key}</Text></TouchableHighlight>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the best way that i know, make all the screen as component and import it in the signup screen

signup.js

```
/*
import all you component(pages) here...
*/

const [screen, setScreen] = useState(1)

{screen == 1 ? (
    <ScreenOne 
      onNext={()=>setScreen(2)}
    />
) : screen == 2 ? (
   <ScreenTwo
      onNext={()=>setScreen(3)}
    /> 
) : screen == 3 ? (
   <ScreenThree 
      onNext={()=>setScreen(4)}
    /> 
)

}
```

You can pass all your state and callback function from signup page to all the component get value from the component